# c++ breaking up a vector in groups of 7

Tags: c++, regex, vector

I have stdout data being inserted into a vector that I need put in groups of 7 (reflecting the inbound data) following a pattern match so that each element [0-6] can run computations (i.e. vrecords[2] = "dog";

I either end up with an infinite loop, only first 7, 7 groups of 7 looped seven times or garbage. I cannot produce 4 sets of seven unique records.

inbound data:

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

expected output:

```
found buy
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
found buy
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
found buy
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

code:

```
char *data()
{
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = stdout
        char * cstr = buff;
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator g;
        vector<std::string> vrecords;
        while(std::fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL){
                //get rid of null termination from fgets
                size_t n = std::strlen( buff );
                if ( n && buff[n-1] == '\n' ) buff[n-1] = '\0';
                //push everything into vector
                if ( buff[0] != '\0' ) vrecords.push_back( buff );
        }
        int count;
        count = 0;
        for(int t = 0; t < vrecords.size(); ++t){
                auto vecbuy = std::find( vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), "Buy" );
                auto vecsell = std::find( vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), "Sell" );
                if ( vecbuy != vrecords.end() ){
                        //cout << vrecords[t] << " " << endl;
                        cout << "found buy" << endl;
                }
                if ( vecsell != vrecords.end() ){
                        cout << "found sell" << endl;
                }
                if ( count == 6){
                        for(g=vrecords.begin(); g!=vrecords.end(); ++g){
                                std::cout<<(*g)<<std::endl;
                        }
                        count = 0;
                }
                ++count;
                //cout << vrecords[t] << " " << endl;

        }
}
```

existing output:
[output](https://bpaste.net/show/ed51a273dce6)

Comment: This one was stated a while ago with the very same sample data and had (as far as I can tell) a valid answer (ok...- it was my answer) and was removed afterwards.

Comment: Nope. Either one side worked or the other. never both at the same time. Which is where the issue comes in.

Comment: @bro The logic in your `for (int t=0` is totally wrong if that's the output to expect.

Comment: @bro - You also failed to return a char*, as your `data` function is supposed to return a value.  So as it stands, your code produces undefined behavior.

Comment: if I change t < vrecords.size(); to t < 7; I only get the first 7 records. It dumps the rest.

Comment: @bro - Since the number of records is 7, just read 7 records into a "transaction" data type.  Then when a counter hits 7, you output the transaction and start a new transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this.
It should be a lot cleaner version of what you are looking for

```
char *data(){
        FILE *fp = stdout;
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        bool more = true;
        do {
                vector<string> vrecords;
                for (int t = 0; (t < 7) && (more = (fgets(buff, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL)); ++t) {
                        size_t n = strlen(buff);
                        if (n && buff[n - 1] == '\n')
                                buff[n - 1] = '\0';
                        //push everything into vector
                        if (buff[0] != '\0')
                                vrecords.push_back(buff);
                }
                bool buy, sell;
                if ((buy = find(vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), "Buy") != vrecords.end())){
                        cout << "Found buy!" << endl;
                        cout << vrecords[2] << endl;
                }
                if ((sell = find(vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), "Sell") != vrecords.end())){
                        cout << "Found sell!" << endl;
                }
                if (buy || sell) {
                        for (auto it = vrecords.begin(); it != vrecords.end(); ++it)
                                cout << *it << " " << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                }
        } while (more);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not c++ fluent, but the logic is here. You can use the modulo and store the two first values of each block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char buff [50], value[2][50];
    int i=0, j=0;

    pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
    else {
        while ( fgets (buff , 50 , pFile) != NULL )
            if (2 > (j = i++%7)) // buff contains one of the two first items
                strcpy(value[j], buff); // these items are stored in the value array
            else if (j==2) {            // the third item
                if (!strcmp(buff, "Buy\n"))
                    cout << "Buy found" << endl;
                cout << value[0]
                     << value[1]
                     << buff;
            } else // other items
                cout << buff;
        fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte   When I try and print out data in the place I need it (in the if validations), I get no output  https://bpaste.net/show/d2b9134645d7

Comment: @bro: What I have posted is a working code that give exactly the expect output, you only need to change it to make it more c++ compliant. Note that in your fiddle, you try to display `value[3]` that doesn't exist, since this array has only two items (0 and 1) to store the two first values of each blocks. So take the time to understand how this code works and adapt the idea to your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the loop that is hard to understand, write the code so that it not only is understandable, it is easily maintained and debugged if necessary.

Create a "Transaction" type:

```
#include <string>

struct Transaction
{
    bool m_isbuy;  // buy or sell
    std::string trans_date;  // date
    std::string trans_number;  // number
    std::vector<std::string> trans_data;  // vector of the data
};
```

Now, create a function that when given a record count, fills the field in Transaction with the data:

```
void addToTransaction(Transaction& trans, const std::string& data, int nWhich)
{
    switch (nWhich)
    {
        case 1:
            trans.trans_number = data;
        break;
        case 2:
            trans.trans_date = data;
        break;
        case 3:
            trans.m_isbuy = (data == "Buy");
        break;
        default:
            trans.trans_data.push_back(data);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that each case in the switch statement changes the item in the passed-in `Transaction` type.

Next, we get to the output function.  It is very simple:

```
void outputInformation(const Transaction& trans)
{
    cout << "found " << (trans.m_isbuy ? "buy" : "sell") << "\n";
    cout << trans.trans_number << "\n";
    cout << trans.trans_date << "\n";
    cout << (trans.m_isbuy ? "Buy" : "Sell") << "\n";
    copy(trans.trans_data.begin(), trans.trans_data.end(), ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Basically, we take a Transaction, and output the information for the Transaction.  The code may be a little advanced, but it's only output.  You can change it to something simpler if need be.

Last, the main() function:

```
int main()
{
    // open the data file
    ifstream ifs("data.txt");
    if (ifs)
    {
        std::string bufLine;
        // start with new transaction
        int counter = 0;
        Transaction curTrans;

        // start loop
        while (getline(ifs, bufLine))
        {
            // change the transaction field
            addToTransaction(curTrans, bufLine, counter+1);
            ++counter;

            // check if we need to output the info
            if (counter == 7)
            {
                // output info and start all over
                outputInformation(curTrans);
                curTrans = Transaction();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You see we're not doing anything to find carriage returns.  It is very simple.

1) We open the file.

2) We start a counter at 0.  For each line read in the file, we call the function to change the item in the transaction data type.

3) When the counter hits 7, we output the transaction and clear out the transaction for another transaction.

The code is a little longer than the loop, but compare the readability of this code with that loop you wrote.  Anyone with a small knowledge of C++ can understand and follow it.

Here is a live demo of my code: http://ideone.com/GIUeKQ

The demo only takes input from `cin`, so it is slightly different than the code in the answer.  Just change the input from `cin` to `ifs` and it should work.